# There was no endpoint listening at [url] that could accept the message

Tags: wcf

I see there are several similar topics on the web and SO regarding this, but none of them have been helpful in solving this issue for me.

I have a wcf service, which is hosted and consumed by the same web application (don't ask why) in IIS. 
So my web.config looks like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Management.Service.ManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="Management.Service.ManagementServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint name="default" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" contract="Management.Service.IManagementService" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Management.Service.ManagementServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="default" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                                 realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="default"
            contract="Management.Client.IManagementService" name="default" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This works absolutely fine in my local environment, and I can even browse to the service (production) in any browser. But when for some reason, I get the `There was no endpoint listening` error on my production server.

I also tried adding the following block after the `<system.serviceModel>` tag to enable tracing, but I don't see any trace file being generated.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="C:\inetpub\WcfClient.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml"/>
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, if I try to consume the production service from local environment, it works fine!

Comment: Why are you hosting the service and consumer in the same process? This makes zero sense.

Comment: @hugh - Okay, here's why - I have multiple instances of the same web application, which serve different organizations. The service in question exposes certain data of the instance it runs in (this data can vary from instance to instance). Each instance has knowledge of other services running in other instances (url of the service is stored in the database). There is a certain module in the web application, which basically fetches data from all the services it knows and displays it. So basically the purpose is to show data of associated organizations.

Comment: So each of your services is running in a different instance of w3wp.exe? And the client for each web app is also only calling services running in different w3wp processes?

Comment: @hugh Yes. Each web application has its own service running. Each web application could know about 1 or more other services and fetch data from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turned out to be a totally different issue.
Turned out that the web application (and in effect the service) was in-accessible from the server itself, i.e. if I try to browse the site from the server itself, I would get a "Page not found" message.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue . In my case the server which I was making a call had firewall issue. They didnot open firewall. After they opened it problem is fixed.